# newOpenFileActivityBuilder().setActivityStartFolder(DriveId folder) doesn't function

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I've been adding the recent Google Drive API capabilities to my Android application and found an issue with:

`com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityBuilder.setActivityStartFolder(DriveId folder)`.

No matter what set as the DriveId, it always opens to the root Google Drive folder.  I know I have the correct DriveId because it works with:

`newCreateFileActivityBuilder().setActivityStartFolder(DriveId folder)`.

Here's the [OpenFileActivityBuilder documentation].([https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/OpenFileActivityBuilder.html#setActivityStartFolder(com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/OpenFileActivityBuilder.html#setActivityStartFolder%28com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId%29)).

In my search for answers, I've found others with the [same issue](https://github.com/fiskurgit/bbcmicro/blob/master/src/com/littlefluffytoys/beebdroid/Beebdroid.java).  There's a comment near the .setActivityStartFolder that says //doesn't work!

```
    IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
            .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
            .setMimeType(new String[]{ "text/xml"})
            .setActivityStartFolder(DriveId.decodeFromString( preferences
               .getString("FitnessAssessmentFolderDriveId", ""))) //doesn't work
            .build(mGoogleApiClient);
```